# Getting Error while installing the titan.Core in Cygwin

Tags: installation, cygwin, titan

While installing the **titan.core** provided by the link (https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse/titan/titan.core) using Cygwin in Windows 10 by following the
steps provided in the file **README.cygwin** provided by **Eclipse** by updating the paths in the scripts and create the Make files **(Makefile.personal)** as below,
getting the Installation error in the Error details.

**Steps followed in README.cygwin in the below link:**

```
https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse/titan/titan.core/-/blob/master/README.cygwin?ref_type=heads
```

**Makefile.personal** file:

```
TTCN3_DIR := C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install
JDKDIR := C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
JNI := no
GUI := no
GEN_PDF := no
DEBUG := no
OLD_LIBEDIT := yes
CPPFLAGS := -I C:\cygwin64\usr\include -L C:\cygwin64\lib
```

**Commands given for installation (provided in README.cygwin):**

```
make dep

make -j

make install
```

**Error Details:**

```
mkdir -p C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/bin
cp ttcn3_profmerge.exe C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/bin
mkdir -p C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/man/man1
cp ttcn3_profmerge.1 C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/man/man1
mkdir -p C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/include/RT1
cp RT1/TitanLoggerApi*.hh C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/include/RT1
cp: target 'C:cygwin64homeSUBBARAMAIAHInstall/include/RT1' is not a directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:295: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/core'
make: *** [Makefile:77: install] Error 2

SUBBARAMAIAH@SUBBARAMAIAH ~/titan.core
```

I would appreciate your help in understanding and resolving the cause of this error. Thank you.

Comment: check which `make` you are running, a windows or cygwin one. Notice that the slashs are missing in the erroring command. `cp` is a cygwin command and wants to see '/' instead of '\\'.

Comment: Thanks @DougHenderson, I have checked and modified the **Makefile** by the **'/'** instead of **'//'** and its 
compiled successfully, executed the **helloworld.ttcn** in demo folder , but getting the error as follows:
**rm -f MyExample.hh hello_world.hh
rm -f MyExample.cc hello_world.cc
rm -f compile PCOType.d  MyExample.d hello_world.d
rm -f tags *.log
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/Install/demo'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/hello'
chmod -R +r,go-w C:/cygwin64/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/Install/
make: *** [Makefile:78: install] Error 1**

Comment: Do not use Windows style directory names  but use instead POSIX style . `C:\cygwin64\usr\include` -> `/usr/include` , `C:\cygwin64\lib` -> `/lib` and  `C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install` - > `/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/Install`. I am not sure JDK will work as it is a NOT Cygwin application

Comment: Thanks @matzeri for the suggestion, I have tried as mentioned POSIX style in the **Makefile** and getting the same error as below 
**rm -f MyExample.hh hello_world.hh
rm -f MyExample.cc hello_world.cc
rm -f compile PCOType.d  MyExample.d hello_world.d
rm -f tags *.log
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/Install/demo'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/hello'
chmod -R +r,go-w C:/cygwin64/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/Install/
make: *** [Makefile:78: install] Error 1

SUBBARAMAIAH@SUBBARAMAIAH ~/titan.core**

Comment: why install should call `rm -f ..`  and why you have still `C:/cygwin64/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/Install/`  ? Have you tried to just use the standard Makefile provide with the project ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the standard **Makefile** coming with the project. But still the same error as above comment mentioned as 
***cd /home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/Install/demo && make clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/Install/demo'*** 
Removing all the MyExample files and hello_world files
***rm -f tags *.log
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/Install/demo'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/hello'
chmod -R +r,go-w ./Install
make: *** [Makefile:78: install] Error 1***